# Why hasn't my profile picture updated on SE.com?

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, profile-picture, caching

I changed my profile picture across SE on May 23rd. My profile picture on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/users/5129611/mithrandir) still hasn't updated, though.

I've used *Update profile info* several times, and it still hasn't changed. I see the old picture (Sauron):

[image]

Why isn't this changing?

Comment: Is this still happening? What site are you trying to sync your profile from?

Comment: @AdamLear - I just tried to sync it again, from [literature.se]. No dice.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. No exceptions on our end. This may be a moot point as we have plans to do a bunch of refactoring around how se.com works in terms of user profiles (I don't know the details off-hand, though).

Comment: @AdamLear Would this require a re-save or should it reset automatically? Mine hasn't updated in over a year, despite repeated (at least 5-6 changes) in that time.

Comment: @catija It’s not automatic if you ever sync’d it from a specific site in the past.